# How to check if a Query is VALID or not using JOOQ?

Tags: java, jooq

I am using the Framework Jooq in the persistence layer of my Java application and I would like to allow a part of a condition of a specific select query to be created via [plain SQL API](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/) in a certain context. The string that makes up the plain SQL part is to be saved at a certain point in runtime and the query is to be executed at a later point in time va a background job.

Is there a way to verify that a Jooq query can be executed without error without actually executing it? For example, I have found

```
ctx.explain(query)
```

which I could use as a workaround, but actually I don't want to execute explain. Is there an alternative to this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some other "tricks" that might be sufficient:

- If your queries are always `SELECT` queries, you could wrap them in a derived table like `SELECT * FROM (...) t WHERE false`. This probably helps cover 95% of all syntaxes, and most optimisers should be smart enough to avoid running the derived table (do check). Some caveats:

  - `FOR UPDATE` clauses and other similar `SELECT` features won't work this way
  - The derived table isn't allowed to project the same column name multiple times
- Use [jOOQ's SQL parser](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-parser/) to parse your query. It can parse a lot of SQL, though obviously not everything, so you might run into parser limitations for perfectly fine vendor specific SQL
- Run your query against a dummy schema / database in your actual RDBMS. If you are certain that your plain SQL template doesn't access your production schema directly, then using a different database on the same instance with the same logical schema could help validate the query without any performance issues, as you wouldn't have any data.
- Run your query against a dummy RDBMS instance, e.g. run from docker. You could even spin it up on the fly using [testcontainers](https://testcontainers.com). It is likely you already have (or soon will have) an integration test setup using testcontainers anyway, so you could simply re-use that to some extent.